# How to get Literal instead of Union type in TypeScript

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I created a function for creating dynamic element. But instead of returning the literal type of the element it is returning the union of `<HTMLElementTagNameMap>`.

```js
function createElement(type: keyof HTMLElementTagNameMap) {
  return document.createElement(type)
}
```

If we just use the above function it is returning the Union of :

```js
(HTMLElement | HTMLObjectElement | HTMLAnchorElement | HTMLAreaElement | HTMLAudioElement | ... 57 more ... | HTMLVideoElement).
```

What I have tried so far :

```js
type valueOf<T> = T[keyof T]

function createElement<T extends valueOf<HTMLElementTagNameMap>>(type: keyof HTMLElementTagNameMap) {
  return document.createElement(type) as T
}
```

*P.S - I am also quite confused! How'd the above function worked?*

but instead using the above function in the way like mentioned below :

```js
const div = createElement<HTMLDivElement>('div')
```

I want it to infer automatically the type of `type` like it does when we use :

```js
let li = document.createElement('li')
```

Answer (score 1):

The code works because you're passing the return type manually by the generic type `T`.

you can automate that by the code below:

```js
const createElement = <K extends keyof HTMLElementTagNameMap>(name: K): HTMLElementTagNameMap[K]{
  return document.createElement(name)
}

const div = createElement('div')
console.log(div)
// [LOG]: HTMLDivElement: {}
```

it's not so different than the one you've written. I hope it helped. if you have any questions you are welcome to ask in comments

Comment: isn't what I wanted!!

Comment: @KunalTanwar maybe I'm not understanding the question; you said "I want it to infer automatically the type of type like it does when we use document.createElement". well the typescript doc itself declared `(method) Document.createElement<K extends keyof HTMLElementTagNameMap>(tagName: K, options?: ElementCreationOptions | undefined): HTMLElementTagNameMap[K]`. witch is really close to my answer

Comment: Well it does!! I was ignoring the typo error

Answer (score 0):

If you want the same behaviour as `document.createElement` you can write simply

```
function createElement<K extends keyof HTMLElementTagNameMap>(type: K) {
  return document.createElement(type);
}
```

or if you want to pick tag name by HTML element, you can use something like this

```
type PickTagNameForHTMLElement<TargetElement> = {
  [K in keyof HTMLElementTagNameMap]: HTMLElementTagNameMap[K] extends TargetElement ? K : never;
}[keyof HTMLElementTagNameMap];

function createElement<TargetElement extends HTMLElement>(type: PickTagNameForHTMLElement<TargetElement>) {
  return document.createElement(type);
}
```

Comment: still the same problem! still returning union of different element types!!